# Find all subdirectories in path with partial string name

Tags: c#, path, streamwriter

I am trying to get all the subdirectories from a path, inserting only a partial string for the name.

For example, inserting: "@abc" it should search all the directories with "@abc" present in their name and do an action for each of them.

```
    string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Users\Usr\Desktop",
                           "@abc",
                           SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    foreach (var item in directories) { 
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(item+@"/test.txt", false))
              writer.Write("test");
    }
```

The example above should search for all directories with "@abc" in the name, open the directory and write a txt file in it, but, it doesn't work. it's only searching for the exact folder name

Comment: Try `*@abc*` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

I had to use a Directory type instead.

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Usr\Desktop");
DirectoryInfo[] directories = dir.GetDirectories("*" + "@abc" + "*.*");
```

With this I can find all subdirectories with partial name

Comment: I have one suggestion, you can get the desktop path in better way like this `string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);`